# Showing 2 linear transformations are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, linear-transformations

I've been given a vector space M and inner prduct space N. 
There are 2 linear transformations A, B defined as
A,B:M->N
Also, <Am,n> = <Bm,n> for all m,n in M,N respectively. I need to show that A = B.

The steps I've taken so far (I'm not sure if I'm doing the right way): 
Take basis for n: $ {n_1,...,n_n}$
$$Am = a_1n_1+...+a_nn_n$$ $$Bm = b_1n_1+...+b_nn_n$$ $$n=c_1n_1+...c_nn_n$$
 <Am,n> = <Bm,n> 
$=> a_1c_1||n_1||^2+...+a_nc_n||n_n||^2 = b_1c_1||n_1||^2+...+b_nc_n||n_n||^2$

I can prove $n_i$ is always non zero since it forms a part of basis and since it is squared it is greater than 0. But how do I move forward from here?

Comment: for -> use \to , for < > use \langle \rangle,

Comment: Don't take a basis, try to think basis free. Let $C = A-B.$ You can view your question as having a map $C:M \to N$ such that $\langle Cm, n \rangle = 0$ for all $(m,n)\in M \times N,$ and you want to prove $ C = 0$ i.e. that $C$ is the zero map, the linear transformation that sends every element of $M$ to $0.$ In the condition $\langle Cm, n \rangle = 0,$ think about what you could substitute in place of $n$ that leads to a statement about $Cm.$

Comment: In order to prove that Cm=0 vector, we need to take n such that each ni != 0, in fact, all positive since there is also a possibility that their linear combination can end up being 0. For non-zero vector of each ni if we use ni's as basis vectors of N we get <Cm,n> = c1n1.n1+...cnnn.nn = c1||n1||^2+cn||nn||^2 and since all ||ni||^2>0 only way this is possible is when all ci's are 0. Hence C = 0. Does this sound right?

Comment: I just realized it, but if we substitute n as Cm for each m in M, <Cm, Cm> = 0. Self inner product is 0 only if the vector is 0. Therefore Cm=0 which gives that C is a 0 transformation

Comment: Yes, you've got it.